# Iterating through HTMLcollection in React,js

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, htmlcollection

I am having trouble iterating through and HTMLCollection in a React.js component. I have the following function:

```
shuffleLists = () => {
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
        console.log(elems)

        for (let item of elems) {
          console.log(item);
        }   
    }
```

`console.log(elems)` prints out an HTMLCollection of `ul` elements as expected. But the for loop after it doesn't print anything in the console, when I would expect to see each `ul` element printed in the console. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit for clarity:**

The key issue here is that the line `console.log(item)` inside the loop does not output anything into the console in chrome dev tools, and the same applies to other various loop syntaxes as discussed in the answers and comments below.

I also have noticed that there is different lengths being logged from `console.log(elems)` between different browsers. In chrome I see `HTMLCollection[] length: 10 ...`
But in Firefox I see 
`HTMLCollection {length 0} ...`

Comment: The problem is likely related to the idea of [React Lifecycle](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_lifecycle.asp), which the `HTMLCollection` has not been `mounted` when the function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my problem was that I was calling the `shuffleLists` function from the parent component in React, prior to the `ul` and `li` elements I wanted to iterate through being rendered in the sub-component. The console output for the `elems` var was confusing as it showed all the lists and list items inside the `HTMLCollection`.

When I moved the `shuffleLists` function to the sub-component and called it inside `componentDidMount` I was able to loop through and console out all the list items as desired.

Answer (score 3):

The `item` in your for loop is actually the key (array index). You need to get the particular element from the `elems` array by using the syntax `elems[item]`.

Refactoring your code (and changing `item` to `key`, just for clarity):

```
shuffleLists = () => {
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
        console.log(elems);

        for (let key of elems) {
          console.log(elems[key]);
        }   
    }
```

**UPDATE**: because result of `getElementsByTagName()` is a NodeList

```
shuffleLists = () => {
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
        console.log(elems);

        elems.forEach(function(val) {
          console.log(val);
        })
    }
```

From the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

> Although `NodeList` is not an `Array`, it is possible to iterate over it
>   with `forEach()`. It can also be converted to a real `Array` using
>   `Array.from()`.
>
> However, some older browsers have not implemented `NodeList.forEach()`
>   nor `Array.from()`. This can be circumvented by using
>   `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

As per the updated requirement of the OP

```
shuffleLists = () => {
        var ulElems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
        console.log(ulElems);

        for(i = 0; i < ulElems.length; i++) {
            var liElems = ulElems[i].getElementsByTagName("li");
            for(j = 0; j < liElems.length; j++) {
                console.log(liElems[j].innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification on the key in the iteration. Unfortunately, I am still getting nothing printing in the console from the for loop. It seems as though that code is not running or 'elems' is somehow empty, although the line 'console.log(elems)' prints "HTMLCollection []" in the console, and I can drill down to the items inside the array in the chrome dev tools. Could there be some React specific syntax I'm missing maybe?

Comment: I have added an update to the answer, please check if that works for you?

Comment: This now throws error: 'TypeError: elems.forEach is not a function'. I looked up the error and tried:   

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems, child => {
    console.log(child)
 });

But this doesn't print anything in the console either.

Comment: If the `forEach()` method is not working for you, can you try `for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++) { console.log(elems[i].innerHTML) }`. Also, I am not clear, if you need to print out the contents of all `ul` tags or loop through `li` tags inside a `ul`?

Comment: The regular for loop does not print anything in the console either - very strange. My goal is to get all ```li``` instances inside each ```ul``` on the page, and shuffle them.

Comment: Ahh, so your question is somewhat different than what you need. Let me edit the answer for your current needs.

Comment: Thanks, the updated loop is correct for my eventual needs but I am still not seeing anything in the console, so I think there is a fundamental issue with my ```elems``` variable. I will have to try and refactor some things I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204864/discussion-between-akshit-mehra-and-silentdesigns).

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName` will return an array of elements, in your case array of elements  in the page, so you need to have something like the following if you want to have the first ul

```
shuffleLists = () => {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    console.log(elems)

    for (let idx of elems) {
      console.log(elems[idx]);
    }   
}
```

I would suggest to use `document.getElementById()` to be more precise about your selected elements